# Django 3.2 exception: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, django-3.2

I'm upgrading to django 3.2 but as per it's release notes, it says:

> The SECRET_KEY setting is now checked for a valid value upon first
> access, rather than when settings are first loaded. This enables
> running management commands that do not rely on the SECRET_KEY without
> needing to provide a value. As a consequence of this, calling
> configure() without providing a valid SECRET_KEY, and then going on to
> access settings.SECRET_KEY will now raise an ImproperlyConfigured
> exception.

Error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'users'. Check that 'apps.users.apps.UsersConfig.name' is correct.`

Users apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
```

I think that error is because of such as it was working with django==3.1.7. Can someone help me to solve this? How can i check if my secret key is valid or not and also generate new if needed?

Comment: Is the SECRET_KEY configured in your settings.py file? Did you provide default value for it? For example it should be similar to this:

SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', default='xxxxxx')

Also, provide the full error message

Comment: Added full error. Settings has this line for SECRET_KEY. SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

Comment: Check how "users" is defined and provide the relevant code

Comment: Upvoting the question. I had exact same issue. Yes this started from 3.2.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I don't think your error is directly related to that `SECRET_KEY` change in your question.

[`AppConfig.name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) should be the full Python path to the application. Since you appear to have `users` inside an `apps` module, you should use `'apps.users'` instead of `'users'`

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.users'
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But is this introduced in Django 3.2? I was using same code since django 2.1.

Comment: You should have had `name = 'apps.users'` in Django 2.1 as well. There isn't enough code in your question to reproduce the problem, so we can't tell why it worked on previous versions then stopped working in Django 3.2. There are changes to [app config discovery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#automatic-appconfig-discovery) in Django 3.2, so perhaps it was something related to that.

Answer (score 8):

If your django applications are in a folder like (`app`, `apps`, `applications`, etc..), you have to specify the absolute path in your app_name/apps.py file to the `name` attribute, see the image below.

[image: Fugure 1.1 django apps vscode demo]

On this image my `users` (1) app  is in the `app` folder that's why a have to use `app.users` (3), (4).

Answer (score 6):

I am having this issue suddenly with Django 3.2.  Why now I am not exactly sure, but adding this to my settings.py file fixed it for me.  I need to understand the structural issue causing this.  It might be because our Django project contains many apps grouped together.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

AppConfig.default = False
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.default

You can also set this individually on at an app level. This may be a better solution.  I am still missing the reasoning for why this is necessary.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class DashboardConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dashboard'
    default = False
```

Comment: Do no forget to import AppConfig first `from django.apps import AppConfig`

Comment: I don’t think this is a good idea in general. You are setting the default to `False` for all app configs that subclass `AppConfig`. There isn’t enough information in your answer to tell why you had to do this, but I think there is probably a better solution.

Comment: I don't disagree, but the change in Django 3.2 isn't documented well enough for me to know what exactly in my setup is wrong that caused my app to fail to run in the jump from 3.1 to 3.2.  The proper solution may be to add a setting to all of my AppConfig classes for all of the 'apps' I have linked together in Django, but the documentation doesn't give a clear reason why this change was necessary.

Comment: Using `default = False` = it is completely ignored and Django uses settings by default. Make sure your use the correct path to the module (`dashboard` in your case) **in relation to the manage.py file**. So if you `app.py` is located in `foo/bar/app.py` -> `name = 'foo.bar.apps.your_app'`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to simply delete the `apps.py` file entirely - Django now managed to find the app automatically.